# idiomatic way to block async operations

Tags: scala, akka

I was looking at some open source scala project. and I saw that some are doing something like :

```
abstract class Foo{

def create(implicit ex: ExecutionContextExecutor): Seq[ResultSet] = {
    Await.result(createAsync(), timeout)
  }

  def createAsync()(implicit ex: ExecutionContextExecutor): Future[Seq[ResultSet]] = //implementation

... more like those 
}
```

is there any advantage/disadvantage for calling each method with

***(implicit ex: ExecutionContextExecutor)*** parameter rather than passing the ExecutionContextExecutor in the class constructor:

```
abstract class Foo(implicit ex: ExecutionContextExecutor){

def create(timeout: FiniteDuration): Seq[ResultSet] = {
    Await.result(createAsync(), timeout)
  }

  def createAsync(): Future[Seq[ResultSet]] = //implementation

... more like those 
}
```

is there preferred option ?

Comment: Can you change the title? This is a real question that would benefit newcomers to the language but I came here because the title read like it would be primarily an opinion piece. Or am I just reading too much into it because I've been here too long...?

Comment: @wheaties what do you suggest ?

Comment: Don't know, "Should ExecutionContext be on method or object?" also sounds very opinionated. "Benefit of ExecutionContext on method vs object?" Gah...

Answer (score 1):

The former approach gives you more flexibility as to where the execution of `createAsync` will be scheduled, since each time you can make a decision as to which `ExecutionContext` you want to pass in. Question is, do you need that flexibility? I find that most of the times a single `ExecutionContext` is sufficient, but it is really a matter of case by case analysis.

In general, the first snippet is horrible IMO. Exposing a synchronous wrapper which blocks around an asynchronous operation is usually a sign of a code smell, and code like that doesn't scale well.

Comment: I guess you meant that the first option is more flexible since the executionContext is passed as param in each call . I wouldn't think of it as code smell since they give you the option of a blocking call

Comment: @igx Blocking calls on async operations don't scale. I personally don't like seeing code like that.

Comment: I just saw in large open source projects like phantom https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/blob/752dda5c4493f236a8d304cc0fe57b0660af69db/phantom-dsl/src/main/scala/com/outworkers/phantom/database/Database.scala